# How can I increase my FPS in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve the performance of Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-minecraft)

I'm running a [Toshiba A665](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2370788,00.asp) with Windows 7 Ultimate (64bit) and just installed the latest version of Java.

Every setting in the game is set to lowest, yet I still in the range of 20-25 FPS. I would be content with 30-35.

What can I do to increase this number? Is there a .config or something I can edit, similar to what Team Fortress 2 has?

Comment: [This forum post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-166-optifog-and-optimine-f-hd-fps-boost/ "Minecraft Forums") should solve your problems.

Comment: [Relevant](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-minecraft/14887)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Similar question: [How can I improve the performance of Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-minecraft)*

1. I recently discovered that turning off your sound effects in the options menu increases your frame rate significantly on low-end computers. Try this first, since it's such a simple solution. (Just drag the volume slider all the way down to 'OFF')
2. One solution is using **add-ons** which let you further customize Minecraft to increase frame rates. The one Justin B proposed is fine. However, Notch has mentioned including a lot of this frame rate improving code in his official releases, so it might not help as much as you want.
3. If you don't want to use add-ons, you can take advantage of the built in **skinning** functionality, and testing some low resolution skins, including ones that don't use animations. An example is here: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/113088-deloz-high-fps-texture-pack/ and here: http://evilmousestudios.com/tronic/. Some people report an improvement with these simple texture packs, others do not.
4. **Compatibility Mode** - Some people report improved game performance on windows 7 when they run in compatibility mode for older operating systems like Windows 2000.
5. **Increase javaw.exe priority** - in task manager, right click that process and increase it to just below 'realtime'. You might be surprised by other processes in here that are taking up resources and want to kill them, but I'm assuming you've shut down what you can.
6. There are some system settings you might want to play with. While playing the game, you might get the most out of it by going to **System Properties** (Right click on 'My Computer' and select 'Properties' > **Advanced > Performance**, and choosing to optimize for best performance. This will automatically turn of things like windows transparency and styles that can be sucking cycles out of your graphics card.
7. You can also try **killing explorer** entirely. A lot of games recommend this when graphics are running slow. Kill Explorer.exe in task manager and when you're done playing, you can start it back up using the same (Ctrl+Shift+Esc > File > Run... > "explorer.exe")
8. You can download [this tool](http://gregs-blog.com/2007/12/16/how-to-find-which-opengl-version-youre-running/) to verify whether you're running the best version of OpenGL available for your machine.

Comment: hmm Justin B. THAT reminds me of someone.

Comment: To your second point, using a "simpler" texturepack does not impact performance. It would only work if you'd actually patch Minecraft to use e.g. 1px textures. And the tronic pack is a higher resolution pack (64px maybe), so it would actually decrease performance.

Comment: I recently discovered that turning off your sound effects in the options menu increases your frame rate significantly on low-end computers.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely Optifine it to get an average of about 80%-95% more FPS than usual.
You can get Optifine [here](http://Optifine.net/adloadx.php?f=OptiFine_1.3.1_HD_U_A1.zip).

Answer (score 1):

The optifine mod is the only thing that I've ever used that has actually helped me with my issue with FPS (Frames per Second) on the Minecraft game. Optifine is a mod that boosts your FPS, As well as allowing you to use HD texture packs. It's overall, like a Game-Booster. I highly recommend that you get it!

Comment: This is confusing. What did you try again?

Answer (score 1):

Here try this:

Download something called Game Booster 3.

It is a program that stops unneeded files and programs that you will never use.

Also, go to Start: Computer: Right Click "Properties": Then go into "Advanced system settings" Then go into "Advanced" and then into Performance. Go to Adjust for best Performance, save, then you are done!

Finally, Download Optifine and optimine.