# How to speed up minecraft on my computer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I improve the performance of Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-minecraft)

I need to know ways to speed up Minecraft on my laptop. It is a new laptop with 4g RAM. I could play it with Generally no lag before the 1.0 update. Now I can't take a few steps on the lowest quality settings without lagging. Is there a way to speed this up?

Processor is Intel Pentium CPU B940 @2.0 GHZ -Should be dual core
OS: is Windows 7

Comment: Similar question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-minecraft

Comment: Mine has to do with the 1.0 version.

Comment: The techniques described in the linked question will still apply to v 1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the graphics on fast. Dont run any other programs like Skype, etc. Open up task manager and set the the minecraft.exe to high priority. Also put the view distance on the lowest setting you can.

Comment: I can't find any minecraft.exe process.

Comment: All Java-based applications (whether Java or native compiled) invoke the Java runtime (`java.exe` in the case of Windows) to run. Adjust the `java.exe` process to the highest runtime priority.

Answer (score 3):

As `Dima Thefencingdude Lukhtai` said but you can  also use a mod like [**optifine**](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-100-optifine-hd-c-fps-boost-hd-textures/) to change various features to make it faster.

You could also write a batch script.
To mahe a batch file open Notepad (NOT Wordpad) and click `file`, `save as...` and change the file type to "all files". Call it Minecraft.bat and click save. Now type this text into the file:

```
java -Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -jar "C:\Users\Yourname\PathTo\Minecraft.exe"
```

The `-Xms1024M` is the minimum amount of RAM memory to give minecraft and the -Xmx2048M is the maximum amount of RAM to give minecraft in megabytes. `"C:\Users\Yourname\PathTo\Minecraft.exe"` should be the location of your Minecraft.exe, this can also be just `Minecraft.exe` if the batch file will be in the same directory.

Now save this file and double click it. A command-line window should open. Leave this window open and Minecraft should launch. Now just use minecraft normally but don't close the cmd.exe window as it will close automatically once minecraft has closed. Remember that you can only give minecraft more memory if you have that extra memory, in your computer, to give. If you do not have that extra memory minecraft will crash.

Comment: Note that increasing Minecraft's memory only works if you *have* extra memory.  If you assign Minecraft more memory than is available, it will simply crash.

Comment: @BenBlank Forgot to about that thanks for reminding me. I've added it to the answer.