# Minecraft framerate drop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, framerate

I have an HP Pavilion G6 series.
It has an AMD Vision A4 Dual Core, 6 gbs of RAM and a 750Gb Hard-drive with no dedicated graphics card

Minecraft used to run at around 50 frames with higher settings which I was completely happy with, but since I downloaded Windows 8.1 a few months back I got into the habit of running the Windows compatibility mode due to the issues Steam games have with Windows 8.1. So I figured if I did the same with Minecraft maybe I could get even better performance! After I ran the program my game actually dropped to cap at 25 frames at the most which was not acceptable for me. I have tried to reinstall the game and play it again and it is the same problem, I don't know how to fix this.
Can someone please tell me what to do?

Comment: Can't you stop using compatibility mode?

Comment: Is Java up to date on your windows 8 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve framerate of Minecraft client?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-framerate-of-minecraft-client)

Answer (score 2):

You can try and download/install [OptiFine](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-174-optifine-hd-c7-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af-and-much-more/), which is a mod for Minecraft that improves the performance of the game.

It improved my frame rate quite a bit after I installed it.

Comment: ^I heard that optifine doesn't really help anymore since Dinnerbone has done all that is possible to fix the lag and make it less tough on your PC, Heard it on the Mindcrack podcast. You should check if you have it on Max Framerate in the Video Settings in Minecraft. I think if you have Vsync on it also drops your frames sometimes.

Comment: Although Mojang has improved the frame rate, I still notice a difference after installing Optifine, for me at least. I'm sure the performance varies from computer to computer.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for the more tech-savvy (or you could possibly pay someone to do it):

Run a dual boot system. Do a Google search for [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer). Running this program will install Ubuntu onto your system alongside windows. I find that this is much better at running Minecraft.

When you start up your computer, it will prompt you on whether you want to start up using Ubuntu or Windows. If you want to play Minecraft, you can choose Ubuntu.

If it doesn't work, Ubuntu can easily be uninstalled from Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure all of your other programs are closed and turn off fancy settings to reduce lag.