# How can get better FPS in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

On Minecraft servers I only have around 5 FPS when I'm running around. This makes the game very hard to play. I have tried many things but nothing has worked. Optifine will not download, and I have watched many tutorials on how to install it. I also have smooth lighting off, fast graphics, and minimal render distance. Does anyone know of a way to get better FPS? I have a lenovo laptop running with windows 8.1. I also have 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: What OS are you running? Are you using a modded client?

Comment: Im sorry but im not sure what OS is, but i do not have mods.

Comment: Which operating system. Are you running MC on a PC or a Mac?

Comment: Im on a lenovo laptop, not mac

Comment: Optifine became a featureful tank that hardly optimizes anymore. Use Sodium (plus Fabric mod loader). It's lightweight and optimizes gfx quite a bit.

Comment: @SF. if optifine doesn’t do much if you have a good pc but for bad pcs optifine gives a fairly large FPS boost

Comment: Lenovo makes notebooks for all kinds of purposes for decades, so the brand is a very useless information. What's most relevant for performance is the CPU and GPU you have. A simple way to find that out is to run the Windows standard program dxdiag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve framerate of Minecraft client?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-framerate-of-minecraft-client)

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to increase FPS:

- I recently discovered that turning off your sound effects in the options menu increases your frame rate significantly on low-end computers. Try this first, since it's such a simple solution. (Just drag the volume slider all the way down to 'OFF')
- One solution is using add-ons which let you further customize Minecraft to increase frame rates. The one Justin B proposed is fine. However, Notch has mentioned including a lot of this frame rate improving code in his official releases, so it might not help as much as you want.
- If you don't want to use add-ons, you can take advantage of the built in skinning functionality, and testing some low resolution skins, including ones that don't use animations. An example is here: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/113088-deloz-high-fps-texture-pack/ and here: http://evilmousestudios.com/tronic/. Some people report an improvement with these simple texture packs, others do not.
- Compatibility Mode - Some people report improved game performance on windows 7 when they run in compatibility mode for older operating systems like Windows 2000.
- Increase javaw.exe priority - in task manager, right click that process and increase it to just below 'realtime'. You might be surprised by other processes in here that are taking up resources and want to kill them, but I'm assuming you've shut down what you can.
- There are some system settings you might want to play with. While playing the game, you might get the most out of it by going to System Properties (Right click on 'My Computer' and select 'Properties' > Advanced > Performance, and choosing to optimize for best performance. This will automatically turn of things like windows transparency and styles that can be sucking cycles out of your graphics card.
- You can also try killing explorer entirely. A lot of games recommend this when graphics are running slow. Kill Explorer.exe in task manager and when you're done playing, you can start it back up using the same (Ctrl+Shift+Esc > File > Run... > "explorer.exe")
- You can download [this tool](http://gregs-blog.com/2007/12/16/how-to-find-which-opengl-version-youre-running/) to verify whether you're running the best version of OpenGL available for your machine.

Comment: The link to "this tool" in the last bullet point is missing.

Answer (score -1):

One word, OptiFine. Install Forge, then install the appropriate version of OptiFine from http://optifine.net (Click the mirror links, the normal downloads take you to an adfly)

Comment: While the question is also a year old, the OP specifically stated that Optifine will not work.

Answer (score -1):

I HIGHLY recommend optifine, however you don't necessarily need to install and run forge to get it. optifine probably wont install because you dont have Java. optifine will let you change some settings that can greatly improve your performance, and in order to run it without forge, you just have to get Java, which is a program that lets you use minecraft's file format (which i would recommend you have anyways)
heres a tutorial for how to get both Java and optifine, if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: If the OP plays Minecraft Java Edition, they have Java, and if they didn't - as you seem to expect - this answer would be redundant anyway. Also note that the information from links and even embedded videos need to be included in the answer itself, as links can die.

Comment: the program Java and minecraft java edition are seperate things. Java normally doesnt automatically come with minecraft java edition, as it is basically just a file format software. without java, .jar files wont be registered correctly and nothing will happen when you try to use/open them. and i will just mention, even though OP mentioned that optifine wont install, there is a way to fix that, and often the reason optifine doesnt work for people is because they dont have Java. so, i figured id offer a way to fix it as optifine is such a good fix for fps drops.