# How to fix Minecraft lag & improve performance on latest OSX 10.14.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos, performance

I'm on the newest Macbook Pro using Mohjave, `10.14.1`.

And I have Optifine installed with all video settings set to either `off`, or `fast` and stuff moving around is super laggy and jerky. It's not the internet connection cause Minecraft runs like butter on both my daughters Surface Pros. :/

OptiFine: `1.13.2`

Resolution: `800 x 600`

**My FPS spikes up to the 290 range, but when I move, the lagging starts and FPS drops to 50ish then freezes for a split sec at 0-1 FPS :(.**

I've run with both this JVM turned on and off:

`-Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've also updated the Info.plist file to try force it to use 8 gigs of ram:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>launcher</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mojang.minecraftlauncher</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>favicon</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Minecraft Launcher</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.8.0</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2018 Mojang. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <string>YES</string>
    <key>VMOptions</key>
    <string>-Xmx8G -Xms8G</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Try Mipmap lower. Also, 1.13 is laggy, even on my pretty good PC. If you want better performance, the best you can currently do is playing 1.12.2 instead.

Comment: You indicate it runs like butter on the Surface Pro... which version of minecraft is on the Pro? The reason I ask is that the Windows Store (Bedrock) edition is written in C++ opposed to the Java... The C++ edition is far more performant language when used for this type programming. (Java can be fast on its on, but Java Minecraft isn't.). Out of interest, what FPS do you get? (F3 should show this)

Comment: Also, could you consider re-phrasing so you have a specific question in your post that can be answered?

Comment: @Stese My FPS is usually running high, hit as high as 290 FPS, but it drops to 50-1 FPS when the performance lag hits :( which happens basically every 1-2 secs. Also if I'm on 1.12 can I play with my kids who are on the latest version?

Comment: You might benefit from running the tools in the F3 Menu to gain an idea what is causing the lag. Assuming that you are all on the Java Version and that the lag only happens to you, it would indicate that the issue is the machine and not the game specifically. I'm not sure what options you have on Mac, but could you monitor what the machine is doing while running Minecraft, and crossreference that with the performance... periodic issues like this would tend to be a process with high CPU or HDD/SSD usage.

Comment: I'm 100% sure its because I'm using the new Macbook Pro, it's not the same performance as older Macs :( I'm not sure why I got voted down btw thoughts?

Comment: @LeonGaban Have you checked out SciCraft’s Carpet Mod? Those guys are the premier technical minecrafters and their server runs projects at an insane scale, so they developed a mos to help troubleshoot lag in great detail. It’s probably not super user friendly but if anything can track the spikes, it’s that. Also I don’t know what update the fix was pushed in, but earlier 1.13s he know lag issues due to mob spawning / despawning never having been designed for the number of water mobs, especially cod,  that 1.13 introduced. They’re been patched in recent updates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve framerate of Minecraft client?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-framerate-of-minecraft-client)

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, the 1.13.2 Optifine is pretty unstable. It was released 22 days ago, and there are no other downloads, making the one you have the only one. There are no new updates or more stable builds, so perhaps the problem is that the build you have equipped has a few bugs or issues.

Comment: But I've tried the regular Minecraft build too, also 1.13.2 :( and still laggy.