# Is there anyway to clear lag from minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

I just wanted to know because my computer is very old.
Please don't say things like "turn your render distance down" and things like that.

Comment: If you don't want ways to actually reduce what's needed to run minecraft (like render distance tweaking)... uuh, well there's the other direction, getting a better PC? That said though, you seem to be asking "How can I make this game run better, please don't tell me things that would make the game run better" and that's not really ... answerable

Comment: This question is pretty unanswerable but you can try installing OptiFine and if you play 1.8 or 1.7 you can get Lunar (or Badlion although Lunar gives better FPS)

Comment: Another alternative is to try using Sodium (which requires Fabric) if OptiFine doesn't work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve the performance of Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-minecraft)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it general lag all the time or do you only notice at certain times?  Are you giving Minecraft enough memory to work with?  As suggested, optifine can do FPS enhancements by giving you the ability to fine-tune graphics options.  Lag can be caused by too many mobs bumping into each other.  You could try killing excess mobs in farms or giving them more space to move freely.

Comment: Its at certain times. Usually when loading up a world or pulling up a gui.