# How to get better performance from Minecraft on a i7-8750H and RTX 2070

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

I have been looking around everywhere to find a way so I can improve the performance of Minecraft on my laptop but not sure what to do
so far I have been using things like optifine which does help to some extent but I was wondering if I can improve it further with the use of JVM flags

in terms of flags, I have found few combinations of them

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn2G

-XX:+UseG1GC -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=2147483646
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M

-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=30
-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=150 -XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+UseBiasedLocking
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -Dfml.ignorePatchDiscrepancies=true
-Dfml.ignoreInvalidMinecraftCertificates=true -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat
-XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2048m -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=20000 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=10
```

Not sure which one of these actually would work or if these would work at all.

Here are my PC specs

```
Computer:      ASUS Strix GL504GW
CPU:           Intel Core i7-8750H (Coffee Lake-H, U0)
               2200 MHz (22.00x100.0) @ 3790 MHz (38.00x99.8)
Motherboard:   ASUS GL504GW
BIOS:          GL504GW.307, 06/18/2020
Chipset:       Intel HM370 (Cannon Lake-H)
Memory:        16384 MBytes @ 1330 MHz, 19-19-19-43
               - 16384 MB PC21300 DDR4 SDRAM - SK Hynix HMA82GS6CJR8N-VK
Graphics:      NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070, 8192 MB GDDR6 SDRAM (TU106M)
OS:            Microsoft Windows 10 Professional (x64) Build 19042.867 (20H2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve the performance of Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-minecraft)

Comment: What kind of performance improvements are you after? Are you having framerate issues? Lag spikes? Reappearing blocks? "Can't keep up" error? There would probably be different solutions for these different problems.