# how to prevent lag in minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-redstone

noob here... i started a server with some friends but idk how redstone function and how it can implicate on lagging the server, i builded a pumpkin and melon farm with observers and pistons and it's kinda ok but its the only farm so i'm scared of thinking the base area will handle  being constantly loaded and BOOM server crashed no one can open it ever again...

the question: i'm confused about rendering and lagging, should i build farms far away from my base and spend some minutes afking in the chunk to farm? if yes, should i build them in different areas to prevent stacking too much in few chunks?
how many chunks far away from constantly loaded chunks??
and witch mechanics create lag? i know about to many hoppers and entities like minecarts are better to avoid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve the performance of Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14876/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-minecraft)

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate -- that one's talking about client perf, and this is talking about server perf. However, I do think this question is too broad to be meaningfully answered. Can you edit it down to ask a single specific thing? Right now you're asking about both chunk loading ("do unloaded chunks contribute to server lag?") and about slow mechanics in general ("what entities cause lag?")

Comment: @pppery Absolutely not duplicate. This is a question about server lag (mspt), which is critical for technical servers. The other question is about client framerate - *FPS* and has nothing in common with server performance. And whoever voted 'needs more focus', likely skipped the second paragraph which *asks all the right questions*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render lag, or low FPS is a client-side issue. Your server (if it's on a different machine) can run fine while your game; client is a PowerPoint.

Server lag in ideal conditions on the other hand, is caused by having too many ticking actions (ie. too many mobs, players moving/updating, redstone happening) and cannt process everything fast enough to maintain 20 TPS (ticks per second; times per second the game updates the world state/simulates at).

It is possible to also get performance drops in the client despite ideal network conditions if too many things update at once, needing the game to redraw and re-render more than your computer can handle.

As for what can cause this: *everything*. All entites and some blocks (ie. Redstone, Furnaces, etc.) tick. Some tricks you can employ to prevent this, though if your server is sufficiently powerful (not running on last gen), this should not be an issue. Tricks include:

- Clearing the world (to bedrock) around any highly complex (builds with redstone stretching at least the view limit) builds
- Avoid building entity or redstone heavy contraptions near spawn (spawn chunks are always kept loaded)
- Limit your build scope/size?
- Not doing server intensive tasks elsewhere (like flying tens of blocks per second at the same time as others).
- Have "lagging" builds at least two (server) render distances apart. The default is 10 chunks radius, so 320 blocks.

As always, you can always mitigate this by upgrading your computers/server.

Also, if your client and server are on the same machine, both will lag if one taxes your system to its full capacity.

Comment: A pretty good summary. Worth adding: wiping out entire spawn chunks, being aware of what is laggy, what isn't (entities, esp. hopper minecarts, redstone dust, mobs vs rails, observers, solid blocks), lag mitigation strategies (disabling unused hopper minecarts, covering hoppers with composters, lighting up and covering areas that produce light updates, destroying unwanted items instead of leaving them to despawn, utilizing lazy and non-ticking chunks where their properties are beneficial.